# Azure DevOps Pull work items in tree level in Excel

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-boards

While publishing into project, I can add Tree Level and keep Parent Child in different columns.

But when I pull the tasks, the parent(epic) child(task) come into single column.

How can I pull parent child in different columns.

> List Type: Flat

^ This is giving some hints. But how to change it?

Appreciate any tips. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it. Had to edit the query in Azure DevOps.

Earlier the Query was just a single level. Now this is how the query looks:

[image]

And this is how the Excel looks:

[image]